# Why can't a template that takes a value not accept an integral_constant and uses ()() to extract value?

Tags: c++

Here's a simple example:

```
#include <type_traits>

using test = std::bool_constant<std::bool_constant<true>()()>;
```

I would have thought that since `std::integral_constant::operator()` is a const expression, that this should work.

Repacing `()()` with `::value` does work,  but the question isn't regarding that.

Comment: Use `using test = std::bool_constant<std::bool_constant<true>{}()>;`. This `std::bool_constant<true>()()` is function which takes no params and returns `bool_constant`. If you want to call `operator()` on `bool_constant` you should create it by `{}` then call `()`.

Comment: @rafix07, oh, is that being interpreted as a function that returns a `std::bool_constant<true>` and takes no arguments? FML!

Comment: for me, it is most vexing parse. Try [this](https://godbolt.org/z/VOuG80).

Comment: @rafix07, add it as an answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: By the way, as far as I know in `using something = some_other_thing;`, something is always a type and never a value (constant or not).

Comment: @Phil1970, and your point is...? In the example, `test` is a type which should be equal to `std::integral_constant<bool, true>`.

Comment: @rafix07: You don’t have to use brace-initialization (which can sometimes differ in important ways); you can parenthesize the whole expression (or just the temporary construction).

Comment: @DavisHerring, yes, I suppose, but I would rather not have to add additional typing or moving the cursor around the document to put parentheses around a term, if not needed.  Can you give me an example of where `std::integral_constant<T, I>{}()` would not work?

Comment: @Adrian: No, the `{}` are fine—I just don’t want brace-initialization to be thought of as the only cure for everything since it can sometimes cause its own problems.

Comment: @Adrian In you question, you said **to extract value** so I was thinking that the expression returns a value. You should be careful when you ask a question to be precise as misleading question can affect the credibility of other persons.

Comment: Sorry @Phil1970, but I meant what I said. `std::integral_constant<T, I>` has a `static constexpr` member called `value`.  `constexpr` member function `operator()` returns the value of `value`.